# Decimal Pad keyboard not working properly in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield, uikeyboardtype

I'm developing an iOS 8 app in Xcode 6.0.1 and running it on my iPhone 5 (which has iOS 8.0.2 on it). In my app, I'm using a `UITextField` with the Decimal Pad keyboard type (I use the Xcode storyboard to set the keyboard type). Everything worked as expected when I was using iOS 7 and Xcode 5. However, after updating my software, I'm having this problem:

Every time I click on the `UITextField`, the Decimal Pad keyboard pops up normally (although the decimal button in the lower left corner is a half the size it should be), but then the `UITextField` won't animate upwards above the keyboard (like it used to) and the following message gets printed out on the console (however, my app does not crash):

`Can't find keyplane that supports type 8 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-DecimalPad; using 1425143906_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default`

A number of "solutions" on the internet suggest going to iOS Simulator > Hardware > Keyboards and toggling an option in there. However, I'm not running my app on a simulator; I'm running it on my phone, so this solution does not work.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have the same problem, although no solution yet. Seems like a bug...

Comment: Turns out, the issue with the `UITextField` animation was not due to the keyboard problem. I needed to set up constraints in Xcode's storyboard for the `UITextField`, make outlets for them in my view controller, and use the constraints to programmatically move the `UITextField`. I have that working now. However, the error message still pops up when the decimal pad comes up. I guess I can just ignore it until Apple fixes it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! That's also the way I had to go, worked for me as well! Interesting though, that the same code (animating the frame) was fine before the upgrade of my iPhone 5 from iOS 7.1 to 8.0.2.

Comment: I've the same problem - half a decimal button. Any idea whether its been fixed in iOS 8.1.1 update?

Comment: No, the half-decimal button and the console output appear to still be a bug in 8.1.1. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out, the issue with the `UITextField` animation was not due to the keyboard problem. I needed to set up constraints in Xcode's storyboard for the `UITextField`, make outlets for them in my view controller, and use the constraints to programmatically move the `UITextField`. I have that working now. However, the error message still pops up when the decimal pad comes up. I guess I can just ignore it until Apple fixes it.

**EDIT:**
I reported the bug to Apple.

Comment: And almost a year later, with iOS 8.4.1 out this is still not fixed... =(

Comment: ikr...ugh...ridiculous :[